# ¿Cómo realizar saltos de linea en un campo de texto remplazando espacios con jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, aplicación-web

Tengo el siguiente planteo, teniendo un **html** bastante básico, con únicamente un **textarea** para el ejemplo, necesito, mediante **jquery** realizar la siguiente tarea:

A medida que el usuario ingresa códigos, *ingresar saltos de linea* en el texto para el ordenamiento de los mismos. No se especifica que los códigos tengan un número máximo de caracteres, por lo que no podría, por ejemplo, tomar un máximo de 10 caracteres ingresados y automáticamente insertar un salto de linea.

Debo sustituir/reemplazar los espacios por saltos de linea y no logro realizar este control.

Dejo el html aunque no hay mucho que mostrar y también lo que he estado utilizando/probando para intentar llevar a cabo esta tarea.

```
<div class="value"> 
   <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="field100" id="field100" required=""></textarea>
</div>
```

```
$("#serial_numbers").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#serial_numbers").change(function() {
        $("#serial_numbers")replace(" ", "\n");
    });
});
```

Tambien realice lo siguiente, duplicando el campo y enviando la información a este segundo cuadro de texto:

```
var $obj = $("#field100");
var $obj2 = $("#field101");
  
$('#cmd').click(function() {
    var text = $obj.val();
    var text2 = text.replace(" ", "\n");
    $obj2.val(text2);
});
    
function replacing() {
    if ($obj.val().find(" ")) {
        $obj.val().replace(" ", "\n");
    }
}
```

Con el código de este ultimo caso, logro enviar al segundo campo, los códigos con el primer salto de linea realizado, pero no los códigos siguientes, no se si esta conducta se corrige de alguna manera.

Obviamente, si tienen soluciones mejores, mas eficientes, o cualquier tipo de recomendación, se agradece, ya que no tengo una gran experiencia en js.
Dejo un jsfiddle que estaba usando para practicar:
https://jsfiddle.net/fbarriosIa/2zuscjo1/14/

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para reemplazar todos los símbolos necesitas usar una expresión regular.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $obj = $("#field100");
    var $obj2 = $("#field101");
  
    $('#cmd').click(function() {
        var text = $obj.val();
        var text2 = text.replace(/\s/g, "\n");
        $obj2.val(text2);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formdata">
<div class="field field100 serial_numbers TextField required" style="display: block;">

  <div class="title">
    <label for="field100">Número de serie<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

  </div>

  <div class="value">   

    <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="field100" id="field100" required=""></textarea>

  </div>
</div>

<button id="cmd" role="button">Enviar</button>

  <div class="value">   
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="field101" id="field101" required=""></textarea>

  </div>
  </div>
```